# Finding the form of the remainder $r(\vec{h})$ of a function $f(x,y) = 2x -3y$, in $\vec{x}_{0} = (x_0,y_0)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I have a question that don't know how to solve.

We are asked to find the form of the remainder, $r(\vec{h})$, for the following function at the point $\vec{x}_{0} = (x_0,y_0)$, and use this to verify that the function is differentiable.

$f(x,y) = 2x -3y$

So the remainder is $r(\vec{x}_{0}) = f(\vec{x}_{0})= 2x_0-3y_0$.

Is this correct?

If a function is differentiable at $\vec{x}_{0}$, then:

$\lim_{(x,y)\to \vec{x}_{0}} = |f(x,y)-L_{\vec{x}_{0}}(x,y)|/d((x,y),(x_0,y_0))$.

As I see it, $L_{\vec{x}_{0}}(x,y) = r(\vec{x}-\vec{x}_{0})$. The next step would be to solve the limit.

First, working with two variables is a little difficult, so I don't know if the remainder is defined the same way. Second, I really don't see how to use the remainder to solve the limit.

I really welcome any insight into this problem.

Thanks a lot.

(edited again)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks. I have edited the question to make it understandable.

Comment: The word residue is wrong. Please give the definition of the *remainder* and make explicit what you cannot do.

Comment: Sorry for the wrong terminology. Edited again.